# Rotate animation hover but while moving mouse on hover -> cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to trigger a rotate animation in an SVG on my website. It definetly work but the problem is when i'm moving my mouse when i'm on hover the element it cancels the animation.

So i include an object svg element:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="branching4.svg" id="branching">
    Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

which is a long SVG document but here is stylesheet attached to it:

```
#rectangle1, #rectangle2, #rectangle3{
    perspective: 1500px;
}
#rectangle1.flip .card, #rectangle2.flip .card, #rectangle3.flip .card {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
#rectangle1 .card, #rectangle2 .card, #rectangle3 .card{
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transition:1s;
}
#rectangle1 .face, #rectangle2 .face, #rectangle3 .face{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#rectangle1 #front1{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#rectangle1 #back1{
    transform: rotateX( 180deg );
}
#rectangle2 #front2{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#rectangle2 #back2{
    transform: rotateX( 180deg );
}
#rectangle3 #front3{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#rectangle3 #back3{
    transform: rotateX( 180deg );
}
#rectangle1.flipped, #rectangle2.flipped, #rectangle3.flipped {
    transform: rotateX( 180deg );
}
```

You can see the svg structure in the jsfiddle

And finally the script:

```
window.onload=function() {
    var svgDoc = $("#branching")[0].contentDocument; // Get the document object for the SVG
    $(".st4", svgDoc).css("font-family", "robotolight,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif");
    $("#rectangle1", svgDoc).hover(function(){
        $(this, svgDoc).toggleClass("flip");
    });
    $("#rectangle2", svgDoc).hover(function(){
        $(this, svgDoc).toggleClass("flip");
    });
    $("#rectangle3", svgDoc).hover(function(){
        $(this, svgDoc).toggleClass("flip");
    });

};
```

I also tried with CSS, it's the same problem.

Here is a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7f7wjvvt/

1st question:

**How can i have a fluid rotate transition when moving the mouse on the element ?**

2nd question:

**How can i have a Y rotation that stay on the spot and not translate to the left ? Try it in the fiddle**

3rd question:

**Why the jsfiddle display the svg well in firefox and not in chrome?**
Also, perspective doesn't seem to work in chrome ... WHY ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: for question 1. you can try to add a flag, which determinate when animation end. You can listen to CSS end animation using `transitionend` some artiels of interest: https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think many of the problems you're experiencing are simply the result of bad browser support for (3D) css transforms on svg elements.

Moving the cards `<g>` elements to their own `<svg>` inside an ordinary `<div>`, and applying the interactivity to the div element would make stuff a lot easier.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background: grey;
}
.card-inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform .4s;
}
.card-inner:hover,
.card:hover > .card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner" style="background: yellow">
    Add svg card here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner" style="background: blue">
    Add svg card here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner" style="background: green">
    Add svg card here
  </div>
</div>
```

> How can i have a fluid rotate transition when moving the mouse on the element ?

Once the card rotates, it easily looses hover. The hover state *will* be applied to underlying element though. If you make sure this is the card's parent, you can use this css rule for styling:

```
.card-inner:hover,
.card:hover > .card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

> How can i have a Y rotation that stay on the spot and not translate to the left ? Try it in the fiddle

You'll have to use `transform-origin`, like you tried. It just doesn't work for `svg` elements...

```
transform-origin: center;
```

> Why the jsfiddle display the svg well in firefox and not in chrome? Also, perspective doesn't seem to work in chrome ... WHY ?

Like I said, it just isn't supported properly...

Comment: Thanks mate you got this

Answer (score 1):

**Re your first problem with the flip**

It looks like the problem is that when the cards spin, they shrink. Then the mouse is no longer over the card and when the card moves around again it re-enters and the mouseenter event fires again. Then the whole process repeats (as long as the mouse is moving).

The solution is to prevent the event from firing again until the animation i complete.

There are several ways to fix this, but here is one solution:

```
// Flag to keep track of whether rectangle1 is flipping
var flipping1 = false;
$("#rectangle1").mouseenter(function() {
    // Only toggle the animation if we aren't already doing so
    if (!flipping1) {
        // Add the class to start the flip
        $(this).toggleClass("flip");
        // Set flag to mark that we are flipping
        flipping1 = true;
        // Then in just over a second, turn the flag off again
        setTimeout(function () {
            flipping1 = false;
        }, 1010);
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing this technique working on just rectangle1.

https://jsfiddle.net/7f7wjvvt/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer but for your first question I'd suggest replacing the .hover with a .mouseenter trigger, and for the second one just lose the perspective. 
Also, I tried prefixing your css but to no avail, seems there's some compatibility issues between the browsers here.